# Regarding standard basis and coordinate vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the standard basis of R^2 i.e (1,0) and (0,1). Then the coordiate vectors and basis  are in the same set. Is this right? The coordinate vectors should be distanct from the vector space. I.e in the case of R^2 we should have two distinct but identical sets

Comment: Do you mean that the $2$-tuples of coordinates live in the vector space itself? The $n$-tuples of coordinates of coordinates (if they are real numbers) _always_ live in $\Bbb R^n$ whatever our vector space $V$ of dimension$~n$ and our chosen basis of $V$ are. So if we take the vector space $V=\Bbb R^n$ then the coordinate vectors indeed live in $V$. But this is kind of the fault of choosing a very specific vector space $V$. Also for the standard basis any vector _is_ its $n$-tuple of coordinates; again our choice of a very specific basis is to blame for that coincidence.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think this question is related and my answer to it may be helpful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874382/the-first-primordial-basis-of-a-finite-vector-space

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen what confuses me is that the basis and the coordiate vectors belong to the same set i.e n-tuples. The basis should be elements of the vector space and the compotnet vectors elements of n-tuples. But since this is both R^n it becomes weird. Anyway should one consider them distinct sets? Even if they are the same? They are distinct in any other case such as polynomials of degree n for instance.

Comment: @EricWofsey I am not allwed to comment on that page,but how does he reason when he says $f_{i}=g_{i}$ for all $i$. Is he refering to some kind of combination? Because they are not equal. A change of basis should be refered to as a mapping always imo,

Comment: In *any* basis, the tuples that represent the basis vectors are *always* $(1,0,0,\dots)$, $(0,1,0,\dots)$ &c. We choose to call the “standard” basis those elements of $\mathbb R^n$ that happen to be those tuples in the first place, which then makes the isomorphism between $\mathbb R^n$ and its coordinate representation the identity map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis and coordinates with respect to a basis are related. I'm going to try to answer the question as I interpret it - but I still feel like this question may be closed as unclear.

So a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ is a linearly independent set in $V$ that spans $V$. We can represent any vector $v \in V$ as a linear combination of the basis elements:

$$ v = \sum_{j = 1}^n c_j v_j $$

and we can call the *coordinates* of $v$ the weights $c_j$. That is, we can write

$$ v = (c_1, \ldots, c_n)_\mathcal{B}.$$

It just so happens that this coordinate is itself an n-tuple. However, this should be interpreted as a collection of weights, each of which tells you how many "spaces" to move in the direction of $v_j$. Compare this to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and consider the vector $(3, 4)$. We move 3 "spaces" in the direction of $(1, 0)$ and 4 in $(0, 1)$. Again, it so happens that $(3, 4)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but this gives the weights of the associated linear combination when we expand in terms of the basis.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No. Recall what a basis is: a set of linearly independent vectors that span a space. $(3, 4)$ is not in the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}$ but is a linear combination of the basis elements. You seem to not be clear on what a basis or a coordinate representation is. You will usually be told if an n-tuple represents a vector with respect to another basis - if no basis is given, it is assumed to be the standard basis.

Comment: Sorry, when I said that they where in the same set I did not mean the basis but the vector space. My bad.

Comment: Right, and then I asked myself If one should consider the "associated linear combination" $(3,4)$ to be in the same space as the basis vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. There are two elements $(3,4)$ in some sense, the coordiante tuple $(3,4)$ and the vector $(3,4)=3(1,0)+4(0,1)$. The latter should belong to the same space as the basis elemets and the first not, right? The above two elements would be eaier to seperate if we take polynomials then we have that $(5,7)$ and $5+7x$ are really different. They same should be valid in the R^n setting but it becomes very confusing